# javadocs and source for hadoop core using maven in eclipse on ubuntu

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ubuntu, hadoop

How can I attach javadocs and source for hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar. I want to run my hadoop program using eclipse, on ubuntu and I am using maven solving the hadoop dependency.

I mvn eclipse:eclipse -DdownloadJavadocs=true -DdownloadSources=true but it could not download both javadocs and source for hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar

I am using eclipse Version: 3.7.2.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that for hadoop-core-1.2.1 there is no javadoc nor sources package in [Maven central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3a%22org.apache.hadoop%22%20AND%20a%3a%22hadoop-core%22).

Answer (score 0):

How to build hadoop source code using ant & ivy (hadoop release-1.0.4)

http://rajiv-kuriakose.blogspot.in/2013/08/how-to-build-hadoop-source-code-using.html
This may useful to u